# Facebook 'No fields expansion available"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On the developers page of Facebook I try to get some initial values through Graph API. I have a game App and a fresh token. However on the list with the fields I get 'No fields expansion available"....

Does any now why is that and how can be solved ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us with the graph API call that you are making? it's hard to tell what's going wrong when we don't know what you are doing.

Comment: I do just a simple call (me?fields=id,name) to all possible versions of the API (v2.x) and I got

{
  "error": {
    "type": "http",
    "message": "unknown error",
    "status": 0
  }
}

All the permissions are given